# Tracking State of Array Order

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to track changes between an array before it is reordered and after it is reordered. I have two variables `originalOrder` and `rulesetOrder`. My component is bound to `rulesetOrder` so that when I move an item, it updates that array to reflect its index in the array. Each time I reorder, an event fires and I compare the `originalOrder` to the `rulesetOrder`. At the end of all the comparisons, I set the `originalOrder` equal to the new `rulesetOrder` which was updated.

First time I reorder, it's fine, the `originalOrder` is different that the new one (`rulesetOrder`). If I go to reorder a second time, `originalOrder` seemed to have automatically changed with `rulesetOrder`, therefore is showing no differences between the two arrays.

Here's my code, could anyone please help me out with what I am doing wrong, so that `originalOrder` always equals the previous state of the array when the event gets fired again?

```
OnReorder()
{     
    console.log("Start: " + JSON.stringify(this.originalOrder));
    console.log("New Order:" + JSON.stringify(this.rulesetOrder));        
    this.originalOrder = this.rulesetOrder; 
}
```

When I set the original order equal to `rulesetOrder`, does that bind them together, so that when one changes the other one will as well? Is there a way around this?

First time:

> Start: ["ae74e7fd-a772-4fa2-b2cb-19c7c0bc611f", "1caf3416-9853-49eb-8bda-c3b9017a204a", "9e5fe94d-6c0e-4b85-85f4-38a074badfeb"]
>
> New Order:["1caf3416-9853-49eb-8bda-c3b9017a204a", "ae74e7fd-a772-4fa2-b2cb-19c7c0bc611f","9e5fe94d-6c0e-4b85-85f4-38a074badfeb"]

2nd time:

> Start: ["ae74e7fd-a772-4fa2-b2cb-19c7c0bc611f","1caf3416-9853-49eb-8bda-c3b9017a204a","9e5fe94d-6c0e-4b85-85f4-38a074badfeb"]
>
> New Order:["ae74e7fd-a772-4fa2-b2cb-19c7c0bc611f","1caf3416-9853-49eb-8bda-c3b9017a204a","9e5fe94d-6c0e-4b85-85f4-38a074badfeb"]

Comment: When you set `this.originalOrder = this.rulesetOrder;` that means `originalOrder` points to the exact same array as `rulesetOrder`. You should make a copy of `rulesetOrder` and set `originalOrder` to that.

Comment: Ha... I feel like such a noob. Javascript passes arrays by reference so typescript then does too since it's transpiled to javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are passed by reference, therefore that's how this will work, as pointed out by Mike above, a copy of the array needs to be set to the originalOrder array.